# ¿Como puedo pasar los datos a un ListView?

Tags: php, android, webservice, soap, ksoap

Quisiera saber como puedo pasar datos de MySql a un ListView de Android, he estado intentando hacerlo paro la aplicación se me detiene, ya tengo armado mi servidor web con el siguiente codigo PHP

```
 function getEmpresas($empresa)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbcompinfra');
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die("Fallo la conexión" . $mysqli->mysqli_connect_errno() . ")" . $mysqli->mysqli_connect_errno());

    }

    $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM concesionario ORDER BY nombre");

    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        $empresaArray [] = array('nombre' => $fila[1]);
    }

    $arrayJson = json_encode($empresaArray);

    return new soapval('return', 'xsd:string', $arrayJson);

    $resultado->close();
}
```

y ya me muestra la cadena en JSON pero ahora mi problema es que no puedo lograr que se pase al Listview en Android.

Este es mi codigo en Android Studio

```
package com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.sigc11;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.DAO.DaoEmpresas;
import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.R;
import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.adaptadores.AdapterEmpresas;
import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.adaptadores.AdapterSolicitudNis;
import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.adaptadores.ConsultarDatos;
import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.items.ItemEmpresas;
import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.items.ItemSolicitudNis;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.kobjects.util.Strings;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget.crouton.Crouton;
import de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget.crouton.Style;

public class Datos extends AppCompatActivity {

    //public ListView lstEmpresas;
    public ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> myItemEp;
    public AdapterEmpresas myAdapterE;


    //Conexion ws
    private String ip = "10.169.6.189";
    private final String URL_SERVICE = "http://"+ip+"/sigc11appws/servidor.php#";
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://"+ip+"/sigc11appws/";
    private String METHOD_NAME = "";
    private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;


    private SoapObject request;
    private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelo;
    private HttpTransportSE transport;



    private PropertyInfo empresa = null;

    ProgressDialog dialogAsynk;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_datos);

        //lstEmpresas = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstEmpresas);
        ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> myItemEp = new ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>();

        try {
            //new AsyncronoEmp().execute();


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myAdapterE = new AdapterEmpresas(this,myItemEp);
        //lstEmpresas.setAdapter(myAdapterE);
        //registerForContextMenu(lstEmpresas);


    }


    //***********Metodo para obtener las EMPRESAS*********//
    public ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> getAllEmpresas(String params){
        METHOD_NAME = "getEmpresas";
        SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;

        ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> myArrayWSE = new ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>();
        try {
            request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            this.empresa = new PropertyInfo();
            this.empresa.setName("empresa");
            this.empresa.setValue(params);
            this.empresa.setType(String.class);

            request.addProperty(this.empresa);

            envelo = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelo.dotNet=false;
            envelo.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_SERVICE);
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelo);

            String resultadoWS = (String) envelo.getResponse();

            Type tipo = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>>(){}.getType();

            Gson convertidoJson = new Gson();

            myArrayWSE = convertidoJson.fromJson(resultadoWS, tipo);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return myArrayWSE;
    }

    //****************Tarea Asyncrona para trabajar segundo plano obtencion de empresas**********//
    class AsyncronoEmp extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>>{

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> doInBackground(String... params) {
            return getAllEmpresas(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> itemEmpresases) {
            super.onPostExecute(itemEmpresases);
            dialogAsynk.dismiss();

            if(itemEmpresases.size()> 1){
                ItemEmpresas myEmpresa = new ItemEmpresas();
                myEmpresa.setNombre(itemEmpresases.get(0).getNombre());
            }else {
                Crouton.makeText(Datos.this, "Sin Novedades", Style.INFO).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();
    }
}
```

si tienen algún ejemplo de como puedo hacerlo me ayudaría mucho

las librerías que utilizo es Ksoa2 y SOAP

Errores que arroja el Logcat

> 03-01 10:45:11.257 3911-4035/com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                                         Process: com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app, PID: 3911
>                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>                                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>                                                                                             at com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.sigc11.Datos$AsyncronoEmp.doInBackground(Datos.java:139)
>                                                                                             at com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.sigc11.Datos$AsyncronoEmp.doInBackground(Datos.java:135)
>                                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Esta es la cadena que me manda mi consulta PHP
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la clase que utilizo para los items`public class ItemEmpresas implements Serializable {

```
int id;
String nombre;



public ItemEmpresas(int id, String nombre) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public ItemEmpresas(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public ItemEmpresas(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;

}

public ItemEmpresas() {

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

}
`

y este es mi adaptador 
'public class AdapterEmpresas extends BaseAdapter {

```
protected AppCompatActivity datosAtivity;
protected ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> itemEmpresas;

public AdapterEmpresas (AppCompatActivity datosAtivity, ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> itemEmpresas){
    this.datosAtivity = datosAtivity;
    this.itemEmpresas = itemEmpresas;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemEmpresas.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return itemEmpresas.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertview;

    if (convertview == null){
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)datosAtivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inf.inflate(R.layout.item_empresas, null);
    }

    ItemEmpresas myItemEmpresas = itemEmpresas.get(i);
    TextView txtEmpresa;

    txtEmpresa = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtEmpresa);

    txtEmpresa.setText("Empresa: " + myItemEmpresas.getNombre());

    return v;
}
```

}
`

Comment: Revisa como inicializas tu Asynctask, debe ser: new AsyncronoEmp().execute(arrayValores); enviando los valores del array.  Agregue respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema ocurre en el método `doInBackground()` de tu `Asynctask` y esta descrito como:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>   at
>   com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.sigc11.Datos$AsyncronoEmp.doInBackground(Datos.java:139)

**El problema es que no estas enviando un array de Strings requerido por el `AsyncTask`.**

Esta sería la forma de solucionarlo:

Si tu `Asynctask` esta definido como:

```
class AsyncronoEmp extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>>{
```

debes de llamar el Asynctask de esta forma, enviando como parámetro un array de valores tipo Strings:

```
   new AsyncronoEmp().execute(arrayValores);
```

para que el array de valores sea recibido en `doInBackground()` y usado en `getAllEmpresas()` :

```
@Override 
        protected ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> doInBackground(String... params) {
            return getAllEmpresas(params[0]);
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo pero realice la idea que me proporciono pero al parecer no se si lo hice mal o algo pero no funcionó

Answer (score 0):

En tu clase deberías poner esto para indicarle a gson que es el campo a donde insertar

```
@SerializedName("nombre")
String nombre;
```

y tu json tiene mal el formato, debería ser asi

```
{"Empresas":[...]}
```

pero aun asi esta mal, recomiendo que quites el "Empresas" y solo deje el arreglo, algo asi

```
{[...]}
```